# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 6 column 1 (char 5)

Tags: python, json

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but this is the traceback I'm getting for a "get data" request. Using Python 3.6/Jupyter. Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

  <ipython-input-18-58ecd65ea1d8> in <module>
  1 # get philadelphia data
  ----> 2 phila_data=get_phila_data()

  <ipython-input-17-3e885b099096> in get_phila_data()
  2     url='https://github.com/tjh7019/Capstone_Week_4/blob/master/incidents_2019.csv'
  3     response = requests.get(url)
   ----> 4     return response .json()
  5     # all data is present in features label
  6     features=resp['features']

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self,
**kwargs)
895                     # used.
896                     pass
 --> 897         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
898
899     @property

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls,
object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
355     if cls is None:
356         cls = JSONDecoder

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
337
338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
340         end = _w(s, end).end()
341         if end != len(s):

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 6 column 1 (char 5)
```

I can send the .csv if necessary; I'm just not quite sure where to begin on the fix for this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a request to a server and the response is text/HTML.
The .json() from the Requests library is meant to convert a JSON to a dictionary, and as no JSON is received, you get a decoding error.

Take a look a the .json docs:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

In your case, you can use the raw link from GitHub to get the contents of the .csv

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tjh7019/Capstone_Week_4/master/incidents_2019.csv
```

Once you get the contents you can load it as a CSV.